# How do install Windows and Ubuntu in my SSD alongside with Ubuntu in 1TB drive?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, intel-rst

I need to install Windows and Ubuntu on my SSD. I have 1TB drive  with Ubuntu that is working fine for me.

Whenever I try to change controller mode to RST to AHCI, it gives a warning that your drive will format during this period.  I have  Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

How can I securely install Windows and Ubuntu on my SSD. Without losing data on 1T HDD ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed ubuntu already, install gparted

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

run it , select 1TB hard drive and resize it after that create another partition and install windows on it.